# Asyncio endless non-blocking loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Im studying py asyncio and im having trouble to create an endless non-blocking looping.

I noticed that my tasks stuck pending because im not awaiting the tasks but if I await, the endless loop will be blocked.

How can i manage this?

```
import random
import asyncio


must_stop = False
background_tasks = set()

async def process():
    global must_stop
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    result = random.randint(10, 20)
    if result == 15:
        must_stop = True


async def get_msg():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)


async def main():
    global must_stop
    global background_tasks
    while not must_stop:
        await get_msg()
        task = asyncio.create_task(process())
        background_tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)


asyncio.run(main())
```

**EDIT:**
After some answers, i noticed that my example was wrong. What i can have to change for the following code work?

Non async messege fun

```
import random
import asyncio


must_stop = False
background_tasks = set()

async def process(msg):
    global must_stop
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    if msg == 15:
        must_stop = True


def get_msg():
    return random.randint(10, 20)
    

async def main():
    global must_stop
    global background_tasks
    while not must_stop:
        msg = get_msg()
        task = asyncio.create_task(process(msg))
        background_tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Im trying to create an endless non-blocking loop to emulate a consumer flow but process tasks arent being processed.

Comment: How do you know that "process tasks aren't being processed?" I ran the code, with the addition of `print(result)` in `process()` and it ran until `result == 15` evaluated to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code mostly does what you want: your `process` task runs concurrently with your loop in `main`; waiting for a new msg to arrive does not prevent `process` from running.

I think your only problem is that your code may exit prematurely -- that is, if `process` sets `must_stop`, then your program may exit while there are still pending tasks. You can fix that by calling `asyncio.gather` after your loop exits, like this:

```
import random
import asyncio


must_stop = False
background_tasks = set()

async def process(msg):
    global must_stop
    print(f'start processing {msg}')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(f'stop processing {msg}')
    if msg == 15:
        must_stop = True


async def get_msg():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return random.randint(10, 20)


async def main():
    global must_stop
    global background_tasks
    while not must_stop:
        msg = await get_msg()
        task = asyncio.create_task(process(msg))
        background_tasks.add(task)

    print('collecting remaining tasks')
    await asyncio.gather(*background_tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Running this will produce something like:

```
start processing 12
start processing 20
stop processing 12
start processing 15
stop processing 20
start processing 18
stop processing 15
collecting remaining tasks
start processing 10
stop processing 18
stop processing 10
```

Here you can see there were two tasks still executing after `must_stop` caused the loop to exit.

---

**Update**

It is possible to use asyncio to run a synchronous function in a background thread; see the [`run_in_executor` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). That might look like:

```
import random
import asyncio
import time


must_stop = False
background_tasks = set()

async def process(msg):
    global must_stop
    print(f'start processing {msg}')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(f'stop processing {msg}')
    if msg == 15:
        must_stop = True


def get_msg():
    time.sleep(3)
    return random.randint(10, 20)


async def main():
    global must_stop
    global background_tasks
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    while not must_stop:
        msg = await loop.run_in_executor(None, get_msg)
        task = asyncio.create_task(process(msg))
        background_tasks.add(task)

    print('collecting remaining tasks')
    await asyncio.gather(*background_tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

The behavior is identical to the previous example.

Comment: tks, larsks but my example was wrong. when i have to  await something, the tasks can execute but how to achieve the same result when my "get_msg" is an sync func

Comment: See my update to this answer.